# Method working only for Class which inherit other class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

This is my first post and my Eng is not very well so i hope that u will understand that what I want to ask :)

I have this class struct :

```
public interface IB
{
    B String { get; }
}

public abstract class C : IB
{
  public B String { get; private set; }
  void SomeMethod(){}
}
public C2 : C
{
SomeMethod();
}
```

And now i need to make class which will have method that is allowed to use only by object having

```
 B String { get; }
```

How can i do this ?

THX for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want a class with a method that takes only classes that implements the interface `IB`:

```
public class YourNewClass
{
      public void AwesomeMethod(IB b)
      {
          var stringB = b.B;
          // do something with the string...
      }
}
```

Comment: Oh ...  Yes that what i want to do i try to do many crazy methods and it will that simply ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have made an interface and then inherited an abstract class from it. You could simply make a concrete class of the interface and override method to use directly.

```
public interface IB
{
 B String { get; }
}
 public class C:IB
{
 //now here override the interface method and do whatever you want to do :D
}
```